# Overlay text on background image and convert to one image

Tags: php

i want some suggestions.

i have to do customize image banner means i have to customize text on images.

for example there is a text on image. this text can customize.after submit this background image and text total convert into one image

Comment: Source image + [imagettftext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) = profit

Comment: We are using imagemagick for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`imagefttext`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php)/[`imagettftext`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) and [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)/[`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) (or the corresponding function you need).

Answer (score 0):

To create an image from a text, you can use the imagemagick library http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php